# How can i make the page fixed when a mobile user try to type something?

Tags: html, css

So , when the user tries to type something .. ALL the pictures arent fixed even when i put the position fixed

here is html for menu buttons and pictures

```
<div class="menu-buttons">
  <ul> 
  <li>  <a draggable="false" href="https://github.com/osalyousef" class="menu-button">Github</a> </li>
  <li> <a draggable="false" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/osamh-alyousef-30a279230/" class="menu-button2">Linkedin</a> </li>
  <li> <a draggable="false" href="https://twitter.com/os_fyousef" class="menu-button3">Twitter</a> </li>
  <li> <a draggable="false" href="https://ko-fi.com/osamaalyousef" class="menu-button4">ادعمني</a> </li>
</ul>
</div>




<div class="GithubPic">
  <img draggable="false"   src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/GitHub.png')}}">
</div>
<div class="LinkedinPic">
  <img draggable="false" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/LinkedIn.png')}}">
</div>
<div class="twitterPic">
  <img draggable="false" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/Twitter.png')}}">
</div>
<div class="Ko-fiPic">
  <img draggable="false" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/Ko-fi S Logo.webp')}}">
</div>
</form>
```

here is the css for menu buttons and pictures

```
.menu-button {
    background: #6e5494;
    height: 2.5rem; 
    transform: translateY(-15.75rem) ; 
    float: left;
    line-height: 2.5rem; 
    width: 8.438rem; 
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 0.25rem; 
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    left: -1rem;
  }
  .menu-button2 {
    background: #4692cc;
  height: 2.5rem; 
transform: translateY(-11.375rem) ; 
  float: left;
  line-height: 2.5rem; 
  width: 8.438rem; 
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0.25rem; 
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  left: -1rem;
  }
  
  .menu-button3 {
    background: #4692cc;
    height: 2.5rem; 
   transform: translateY(-7.313rem);
    float: left;
    line-height: 2.5rem;
    width: 8.438rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 0.25rem; 
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    left: -1rem;
  }
  
  .menu-button4 {
    background: #4692cc;
    height: 2.5rem; 
    transform: translateY(-3.25rem) ; 
    float: left;
    line-height: 2.5rem; 
    width: 8.438rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 0.25rem; 
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    left: -1rem;
  }
  
  .GithubPic  img  {
    left: 4.7rem; 
    transform: translateY(-16.2rem); 
     position: fixed;
     width: 3.3rem;
     -webkit-user-drag: none;
     user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
     -webkit-user-select: none;
     -ms-user-select: none;
  }
  
  .LinkedinPic img {
  left: 5.3rem;
 transform: translateY(-11.188rem);
  position: fixed;
  width: 2.3rem;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}   
  
  .twitterPic  img {
    left: 5.4rem;
    transform: translateY(-7rem); 
    position: fixed;
    width: 1.9rem;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
  }
  
  .Ko-fiPic img {
    left: 4.7rem;
  transform: translateY(-3.688rem); 
  position: fixed;
  width: 3.4rem;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  }
  .c0inPic img {
  position: fixed;
  width: 7rem;
  top: 0.3rem;
  left: 0.2rem;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
}
```

i have tried many things , like draggable: false and webkit drag:none and it is still not working
here is a
[picture related:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpZ3b.png)
As you can see her , most pictures got scaled up

It is ok if i elimenate the whole scrolling functions up and down and right and left but it still haven't fix the issue

Comment: First, you should figure out how you want to recognize a mobile user. It isn't as easy as you believe. Then you want to look into Flexbox and Grid. Float is the wrong tool here.

Comment: What do you want it to look like when the user starts typing? Also, please make your code into a runnable snippet so we can easily see the problem on a mobile device see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example